# How can I change the color of the active navbar item?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I have 3 buttons on my navigation bar and I want to change the color of the text to a different one if it is the active page.

I want also to have a default one, the first one.

The StyledLink was from another answer but it's not working. I'm using chakra ui.

This is the code for my layout.js:

```
const StyledLink = styled(Nav.Link)`
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: ${(props) => (props.active ? "red" : "inherit")};
`;

export default function Layout({
  children,
  title = "This is the default title",
  props
}) {
  return (
    <Flex border="1px solid #EDF2F7" padding="2.5px 24px">
      <Text fontWeight="bold" color="orangered" fontSize="35px" mt="-5px">
        Index
      </Text>
      <Nav>
        <StyledLink href="/" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
          <Text ml="70px" mt="1px"  fontSize="20px" isTruncated > //color="orangered"
            LIVE Map
          </Text>
        </StyledLink>
      </Nav>
      <Link href="/requests" style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
        <Text ml="70px" mt="1px" fontSize="20px" isTruncated>
          Request List
        </Text>
      </Link>
      <Link style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
        <Text ml="50px" mt="1px" fontSize="20px">
          Analytics
        </Text>
      </Link>
    </Flex>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `useRouter`. Read more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

You can use this to determine the pathname you are currently on and dynamically change the style. The code below is taken from my website: https://github.com/bjcarlson42/benjamincarlson.io/blob/master/components/Navigation.js

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

// your code here

 const { colorMode } = useColorMode()
 const router = useRouter()

    const bgColor = {
        light: '#fff',
        dark: '#171717' // #1A202C
    }

<NextLink href="/statistics" passHref>
                    <Button
                        as="a"
                        variant="ghost"
                        p={[1, 2, 4]}
                        _hover={{ backgroundColor: navHoverBg[colorMode] }}
                        backgroundColor={router.pathname === '/statistics' ? navHoverBg[colorMode] : null}
                        aria-label="Statistics"
                    >
                        Statistics
                    </Button>
                </NextLink>
                <NextLink href="/blog" passHref>
                    <Button
                        as="a"
                        variant="ghost"
                        p={[1, 2, 4]}
                        _hover={{ backgroundColor: navHoverBg[colorMode] }} backgroundColor={router.pathname.includes('/blog') ? navHoverBg[colorMode] : null}
                        aria-label="Blog"
                    >
                        Blog
                    </Button>
                </NextLink>
                <NextLink href="/projects" passHref>
                    <Button
                        as="a"
                        variant="ghost"
                        p={[1, 2, 4]}
                        _hover={{ backgroundColor: navHoverBg[colorMode] }} backgroundColor={router.pathname === '/projects' ? navHoverBg[colorMode] : null}
                        aria-label="Projects"
                    >
                        Projects
                    </Button>
                </NextLink>

// more code here
```

Now, for your second part of the question: how to make the first one default?

You can do this by adding some more logic. Back to the example above, I will make statistics the default.

```js
<NextLink href="/statistics" passHref>
                    <Button
                        as="a"
                        variant="ghost"
                        p={[1, 2, 4]}
                        _hover={{ backgroundColor: navHoverBg[colorMode] }}
                        backgroundColor={router.pathname === '/statistics' || (router.pathname != '/statistics' && router.pathname != '/blog' && router.pathname != '/projects') ? navHoverBg[colorMode] : null}
                        aria-label="Statistics"
                    >
                        Statistics
                    </Button>
                </NextLink>
```

As you can see, I am checking to see if we are on the statistics page OR if we are not on any of the 3 pages - statistics would still be 'active' because this is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have enough info but I have done it.

You can do something like this

```
const history = useHistory()
<StyledComponent isActive={history.location.pathname === '/'} href='/'>
</StyledComponent>
```

Comment: Can you please be more detailed in the answer? Can I use useHistory() in this component? It's giving me an error.

Comment: `useHistory` is the react-router-dom hook which you can use in react functions.

Comment: It doesn't work this way with StyledComponent

Answer (score 0):

Your `StyledLink` is expecting an `active` prop to change its color. You can use `useRouter` to check the current path, then pass `active` to `StyledLink` based on that.

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";

// ...

export default function Layout({ children, title = "This is the default title", props }) {
    const { asPath } = useRouter();

    return (
        // ...
        <Link href="/" passHref>
            <StyledLink style={{ textDecoration: "none" }} active={asPath === "/"}>
                <Text ml="70px" mt="1px"  fontSize="20px" isTruncated > //color="orangered"
                    LIVE Map
                </Text>
            </StyledLink>
        </Link>
        // ...
    );
}
```

Comment: styled(Text). const StyledLink with "styled(Nav.Link)" or "styled(Link)" doesn't work. It only works with styled(Text) but then the functionality of the href doesn't work, it acts as a normal text. What could it be?

Comment: <Link href="/">
        <StyledLink active={asPath === "/"}>
          <Text >
            LIVE Map
          </Text>
        </StyledLink>
      </Link>
I got it working this way, but it's not updating if I click on the links.

Comment: Would adding `passHref` to your `Link` work? For instance: `<Link href="/" passHref>...</Link>`. If so, I'll update my answer to reflect that.